# Ban a URL from showing up in Google Analytics

Tags: google-analytics

All,
There is a website that doesn't seem legitimate that and keeps showing all of these page views in my google analytics. Is there a way to ban certain URLs from being processed in google analytics?

Comment: Do you mean that you want to exclude an URL from showing up or that you want to exclude certain client hosts from showing up?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson This may be a stupid question but what is the different? I believe I just want to ban a URL but I'm not 100% of the difference.

Comment: Simply put, an URL is a page on your site, a client host is a machine accessing your site.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Then I think I want to ban the client host. Say my website is www.website.com, under my All Traffic one of the sources is www.badwebsite.com. I'd like to ban www.badwebsite.com from showing up.

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson Thanks for the post below. It is showing up as a referral. Does that make a difference? Does Google Analytics store the IP address that is hitting the page?

Comment: Added a link to more info on how to create a custom filter. That should do it for you, one of the types should allow for referral filtering.

Comment: wait hold up, your question says that there are page views showing up from a certain website that you want to block. But now you are talking about referring URLs...those re two different reports...are you saying that you do not want to see any page views that are *on your site*, if the visitor *came from* this certain URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can make an IP address not show up by adding it to a filter.

Please look at http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55481, even though it talks about excluding internal addresses, it should work well as a guide how to do it with the "difficult" site too.

Edit: To filter on referrals you need to create a custom filter.

See http://support.google.com/googleanalytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=55492 for a guide.

http://support.google.com/analytics/bin/answer.py?hl=en&topic=1034830&answer=1034842 talks specifically about excluding referrers.

Note that the filters will only act on future data, the referrals that are already collected will still show up.

Comment: Ok so if I do a customer filter and select a campaign source like in this website http://www.businesshut.com/spam/google-analytics-referrer-spam/? If I wanted to include all of these like for example slowfoodottawagatineau.org, would I need to add a backslash before the .org? How would it look by adding it there?

Comment: Please check my answer for the specific link for excluding referrers. From what I recall, you can use regular expressions to match several hosts, but you should be able to just use the hostname as is too.